# Make hibernate data persistent (WIndows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I'm wondering if it is possible to have hibernate data persist after a restore, so that even after a reboot, the same session I had before would be restored.
I know this would be simple with the use of VM, but I am exploring other possibilities before I go down that route.

I have considered making the files read only or taking permission away from system, though I thought I would come here to see if there is a better way.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to choose to fresh reboot without disturbing the 'saved session' too. I think a great tool would be a program that backs up the hibernation data, and lets you choose which data to have there (if any). I'd also happily do this manually or write a script to do this, my roadblock there is getting my hands on said data, as it is removed after a successful resume isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An issue with this approach is that data could change in the hard drive, and your hibernation state will no longer match with the data on the hard drive when you later restore from that state. For example, what happens if you do a Windows update, and then restore a hibernation state from before that update? Or maybe I'm not understanding your question?

Comment: @Steve this is a possibility, though I tend to not perform windows updates automatically, and would be OK with having to remake the saved states after updating windows / any of the programs running on that state. I would just have to be mindful.
Is there any other changes to the hard drive that might cause issues? General windows temp files? Other things that would be expected to change without my control?
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: this is quite common in the past with [deep freeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_(software)) and similar softwares. However it applies to the whole drive and I don't know if it saves the sate of the hiberfil.sys or not. Anyway if you save the current state when you're opening a document, then save it. When you restore the state then the app still thinks the file is opening so it'll break

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have it both ways.  If you have a saved hibernation state, you must resume from that hibernated state, and that hibernation state will be destroyed once you do.  If you choose not to resume from the hibernated state, it will also be destroyed with the added bonus of the last shutdown becoming an unexpected power loss as far as the operating system is concerned.

The bottom line is that NTFS is highly state dependent.  The filesystem driver keeps a bunch of metadata about the current state of low-level NTFS data structures in RAM (e.g. block pointers to open handles, cache data, journal rewind position, clean vs. dirty RAM pages for loaded blocks, copy-on-write status, etc).

When you hibernate, all of that RAM is copied to the hibernation file and the full hibernated state must remain consistent between reboots.  If even a single byte of data changes on the hard drive between the time the hibernation state is saved and when it's resumed, then the state is no longer consistent and the entire hibernation file is considered invalid.  To act any differently would be as if two different operating systems had the volume mounted at the same time.  They two would disagree about the condition of the filesystem and would walk all over each others' accounting of it, causing severe filesystem corruption.  This is why cluster storage file systems used in corporate SAN networks use a file system that is designed for this purpose.  It's just not possible with NTFS.

Even if you take an offline block-level backup of a hibernated system and restored it to an identical drive, it would still invalidate the hibernation state because the hardware GUID of the drive will have changed and that is also part of the state data.

The only exception to this rule is the HORM (**H**ibernate **O**nce, **R**esume **M**any) feature of Microsoft's Enhanced Write Filter (EWF).  This feature is only available on Windows Embedded versions and the Enterprise version of Windows 10.  This allows you to hibernate the system once and resume from that hibernated state as many times as you want.  The caveat with that feature, however, is that any changes made to the file system are silently redirected entirely to a RAM disk and are dumped every time the system is powered off, effectively making the whole filesystem read-only after that point.

Comment: Nice answer. Added a lot of information that was useful. Thanks for explaining that to me - I prefer to know the why and how, not only the what.

Comment: I also echo Squigz's thanks for explaining the _why_ it can't be done. Particularly frustrating for me as my reason for wanting to reuse the hibernation file is I have an aging, but still useful laptop that sometimes locks up (at a hardware level) very shortly after resuming from hibernation. This necessitates a hard reset: it would have been useful to re-resume from the hibernation file.